# Converting double 1.557760E12 to int

Tags: java, integer, int, double, converters

I have  `double iD = 1.557760E12;` I want to convert it to an int how can I do ? 
someone explaine to me please  thanks a lot ?

Comment: You're not going to have much luck, as the largest (32-bit, signed) `int` is almost 1000 times smaller than this value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. This number, written out, is:

```
1557760000000
```

The max `int` is:

```
2147483648
```

This is clearly much smaller.

You can, however, cast to a `long`. Its max value is

```
9223372036854775808
```

which, even at a glance, is much larger than your double. Use the following code:

```
long iLong = (long)iD;
```

Answer (score 0):

**round()** will always round your double to the correct value, and then, it will be cast to an long which will truncate any decimal places. But after rounding, there will not be any fractional parts remaining.

```
long i =math.round(id);
```